# Inject environment config to angular app at runtime using webpack?

Tags: angular, express, webpack, build, config

We follow CI/CD approach. So same build is required for QA and production. Thus unable to use angular environment `files(fileReplacements)` for configuration variables as build are different.

I choose to inject config via express in index.html via handlebars rendering in angular `build(/dist)` folder.

But when using `ng serve` command how can we inject config to html file via `Webpack` dev server?

I can use `ng build --watch` cmd. But setting up via `webpack` will be better for debugging.